# Sequence formed by zeroes of $f_n(t)=\ln(t)-t+n$ is decreasing

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\geq 2}$ defined on $(0,1]$ by
$$f_n(t)=\ln(t)-t+n.$$
By intermediate value theorem, we deduce that there exists a sequence $(t_n)_n$ with $0<t_n<1$ such that $f_n (t_n)=0$ for all $n\geq2$. Thus we have $$0<t_n=\ln(t_n)+n<1$$ and we can then prove that
$$e^{-n}<t_n<e^{1-n}$$ which implies that $(t_n)_n$ converges to $0$. Using Mathematica I can see that $(t_n)_n$ is decreasing. I don't know how we can prove that. I would be also glad to find the speed of convergence to $0$, which by the above inequality would be something between $e^{-n}$ and $e^{1-n}$.

Here's the graph of those functions for $n=2,3,4$
[image]

Comment: How exactly you are deducing  existence of $t_n$? The fact that it is decreasing should probably follow from how you construct it.

Comment: @xyzzyz for each $n\geq0$ $f_n$ is increasing in $(0,1]$ with $f_n(1)=n-1>0$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} f_n(t)=-\infty$, so by  intermediate value theorem there exists $0<t_n<1$ such that $f_n(t_n)=0$, so the construction does not imply that $t_n$ is decreasing. We construct the sequence only by intermediate value theorem.

Comment: By what you have, $$e^{-(n+1)} < t_{n+1} < e^{1-(n+1)} = e^{-n} < t_n < e^{1-n}\,.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer ah yes I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $ n = t_n - \log t_n,$ so $e^n = e^{t_n}/t_n,$ and $e^{t_n+1}/t_{n+1}=e^{n+1}=e \cdot e^{t_n}/t_n > e^{t_n}/t_n.$

Taking derivatives, we find that $g(t) = e^t/t$ decreases on $0<t<1,$ which proves the theorem.